# How many multisets of $n$ letters can I form with $k$ different vowels?

Tags: combinatorics

How many [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (unlike a set, a multiset allows for multiple instances for each of its elements ) of $n$ letters can I form with $k$ different vowels?

For instance, if $n=4$ and $k=2$ then some valid multisets are:

$$\{a,a,o,o\}$$

$$\{a,i,b,d\},$$

$$\{u,i,k,k\},$$

$$\{u,i,f,g\},$$

$$\{i,i,u,u\}$$

$$\vdots$$

What I tried: well, first I though it was a fairly simple problem, which could be solved using standard tools from combinatorics. But I got stuck at the very start of the reasoning, not able to find a simple formula for the solution...

PS: it does not really matter to me how many letters or vowels exist. I used the alphabet just to illustrate the key idea, but it could be any other set of "letters" or "vowels".

Thank you!

Comment: On this forum, you are expected to first show what efforts you have made, and where you are stuck before seeking help, so pl. edit it in.

Comment: You have posted this question over and over most recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687607/how-many-multisets-of-n-letters-can-we-form-with-k-different-vowels),  despite the fact that it keeps getting closed for lack of effort on your part

Comment: it is not lack of effort, I just do not know how to solve it or even start solving... if please you could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You might be interested in reading the Wikipedia article on Multisets, especially the section on "Counting multisets".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem can be formulated as:

> Let $V$ and $C$ be disjoint sets of symbols.
> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers with $k\le n$.
> Find the number of multisets $S$ such that:
>
> 1. $S\subseteq V\cup C$ as sets
> 2. $|S|=n$ as a multiset
> 3. $|S\cap V|=k$ as a set

First choose $k$ vowels in $V$, which has $|V| \choose k$ ways to do.
For each $k$-tuple of vowels,
we have to choose the number of each vowel in $S$.
Let $k\le m\le n$.
There are ${m-1 \choose k-1}$ ways to choose the number of each vowel
such that the number of all vowels equals $m$.
It remains to choose $n-m$ consonants in $C$,
which has $n-m+|C|-1 \choose |C|-1$ ways to do.
Then the number of ways to choose $S$ is
$$
{|V|\choose k}\sum_{m=k}^n {m-1\choose k-1} {n-m+|C|-1\choose |C|-1}.
$$

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose that we have k voyels, and the multiset has a length of n. For the first letter of the multiset, we have k possibilities. For the second letter, we also have k possibilities since repetitions of voyels are allow. For every letter, we have k possibilities, so in the end, we have  k^n possibilities .

Comment: it is not as simple as that...